# Get files from a specific Google Drive Folder

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am working on downloading a particular file shared with me in Google Drive. I developed the script to get the list of files and folders in my account. In that folders, I need to get the files list. While trying to do this I am getting the below error,

```
Notice: Undefined property: Google_Service_Drive::$children
```

My Code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); 
$optParams = array(
  "pageSize" => 10,
  "fields" => "nextPageToken, files(id, name)", 
  "q" => "sharedWithMe and name contains 'Folder Name'"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
print "Files:\n";
foreach ($results->getFiles() as $files) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $files->getName(), $files->getId());

    $folderId = $files->getId();

    $parameters = array();
    $children = $service->children->listChildren($folderId, $parameters);
  }
}
```

I need the fileId in the folder, so I can download it.

Let me know if I am missing any scope or anything wrong on my code.

Your suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since `children` is undefined, are you sure your sdk matches the documentation? Or did you accidentally typo and should the `$service` on the third to last line actually be `$files`?

Comment: I am referring this document to get the list of files,
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list

I got the list of files/folders and their Ids. In that, I have one folder, I need to get the children files. For that I am referring this, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list

Let me know if my references are wrong @Loek

Comment: The newest version of the api is /v3: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk. Did you include that in your code?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to use through Google client API, check my updated code please @Loek

Comment: /v3 is the same client API, just a newer version?

Comment: okay my current version of Google Client API is 2.0, do you think if I upgrade will the issue be resolved? @Loek

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178366/discussion-between-suriya-prakash-m-and-loek).